# Why regex functions like gsub() in R doesn't identify NA?

Tags: r, na

I am trying to replace `NA` using `regex` functions like `gsub` -

**Sample Data-**

```
a<-c(NA,1:5,NA,NA,1:3, rep(NA,round(runif(1,0,100))))
```

How to identify `NA` in a `pattern` matching field.

For e.g- `gsub("identify NA", 0, a)`

Note- I know other methods to replace `NA`, but I am trying to identify `NA` using `regex`.

EDIT- My intent here is to understand, why regex doesn't identify `NA`?

Comment: This is misguided. You have a numeric vector, with missing values. Regex works on character vectors. Regex doesn't work on missing values.

Comment: Even if my vector contains characters, it won't work.

Comment: See @DirkEddelbuettel's last sentence in his answer as to why regex won't work.

Comment: You can use regex to detect the letter `"N"` followed by the letter `"A"` in text, e.g., `"NA"`. But those letters are not a missing value. `"NA"` is different than `NA_character_` (which is a missing value of class `character`, which prints as `NA`). See, e.g., `is.na(c("NA", "NA_character_", NA, NA_character_))`

Comment: @Gregor Sure. But, I feel question was not misguided. My intent was to understand, why it doesn't  work.

Comment: Prior to edits, the goal "replace `NA` using `regex`" is certainly misguided. The revised request, "why regex doesn't identify `NA`" is an excellent question.

Comment: @gregor  thanks for pointing me to edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have pointed out, don't use gsub. You can use the `replace_na` function from the tidyr package.

```
library(tidyr)
a<-c(NA,1:5,NA,NA,1:3, rep(NA,round(runif(1,0,100))))
replace_na(a, 0)
# [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 #0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 # 0 0 0 0 0 0
# [84] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `gsub()` or other reg.exp functions -- `NA` *already is identifiable* so use `is.na()`.

#### Example

```r
R> a<-c(NA,1:5,NA,NA,1:3, rep(NA,round(runif(1,0,100))))
R> a
 [1] NA  1  2  3  4  5 NA NA  1  2  3 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[30] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
R> a[is.na(a)] <- 42
R> a
 [1] 42  1  2  3  4  5 42 42  1  2  3 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
[30] 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42
R>
```

Here we simply index the vector `a` by `is.na(a)` and, to keep it simple, just assign a new value to those values.

In short, do not confuse the "text" `NA` displayed when printing an actual `NA` value with the condition of an `NA`.